# Use of unresolved identifier 'NavigationLink'; did you mean 'NavigationView'? - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

After updating to Xcode11 beta 2 it seems that `NavigationLink` is depreciated, shows below error.

> Use of unresolved identifier 'NavigationLink'; did you mean
>   'NavigationView'?

Comment: Why are you using XCode 11 beta 2? We're on XCode 11 beta 5 now. There are a lot of deprecations between releases.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [NavigationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) in **Xcode11 beta 2** because it's added in newer beta version. If you don't want to update to the newer beta you should use [NavigationDestinationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationdestinationlink) instead.

You can download newer XCode beta from the [downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/) page

As other option you can use `NavigationButton`

```html
struct DataList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(someData) { data in
                NavigationButton(destination: DataDetail()) {
                    DataRow(data: data)
                }
                
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Data list"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in older version of Xcode 11 beta, you should use NavigationButton instead of NavigationLink, they are the same.